# Autonotify and out of date page views

Tags: discussion, support, comments, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

#### Scenario:

1. I view a post. (Say this one for example)
2. I see a comment below by [kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno) -- `What is the topic, exactly?`
3. I believe I know the answer.  I start composing my response.
4. But [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) was faster and **responds first**.
5. **Without refreshing, I respond** to [kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno) *without explicitly naming @kia*: `I think I know what this question is about...`
6. Now I see:

   - What is the topic, exactly? -- [kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno)
   - Um narwahls, what else? -- [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles)
   - It's about comment notification?  < me >

#### Question(s):

- Did my comment notify [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles)? Or [kiamlaluno](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno) <-- *like I intended*?
- If it does notify waffles instead, could this be changed or should I always explicitly name the user I'm responding to?

---

This edited question isn't quite what i mean (will keep it though as it's related)

I know that if i comment after a single person comments on a post they get notified. What i'm asking is if i load the page before that comment has been made, will it still notify them (even though from my perspective there is no comment)?

Comment: What is the topic, exactly?

Comment: Related information: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: I'm rather certain that it won't notify waffles. My guess is that also kiamlaluno won't get a notification. Best would be to just test this. I'll write an answer - can you please post a comment, @M.Tibbits? Then I'll start composing a comment.

Comment: It didn't notify me because two different users commented before your comment. If I were the only one to comment, then your comment should have notified me, even if you didn't use "@kia"; at least that is what I have understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are asking what happens when you write a comment that is directed to the first user who commented, when there are no other users who commented, you didn't use a @-reference (because you were referring to the only user who commented the post), but when you add your comment, there is somebody else who wrote a comment before you.

In that case, neither the users (the first and the second user) get notified. The automatic notification happens between two users who comments on a post, when there aren't other users who comment. In this case, the automatic notification would have worked if the comments followed this order, for example.

- kiamlaluno
- George Duckett
- kiamlaluno
- George Duckett

To say the truth, the automatic notification for George Duckett always work because he is the author of the question.

Comment: Accepting this as it answers my exact question. i.e. the check for who to send is server-side, so the fact that i'm looking at a post with only one comment when i'm posting mine is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a test. Please don't comment (yet), unless you're M. Tibbits.

EDIT: Now another comment, please.

---

And here the outcome:

The intended @kia won't be notified in this case, and @waffles won't be notified either.  Note M. Tibbits' screenshot:

[image: Silly silly Comments.]

Comment: Sure thing.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: OK, I've started composing. I don't think M. Tibbits will get a notification if I submit this after another comment is posted here.

Comment: So, @M.Tibbits, did you get a notification of my previous comment? (For posteriority: The above comments of M. Tibbits and genesis-φ are both answers to now deleted comments.)

Comment: @Hendrik, Nope I didn't.  I wasn't on the page.  genesis, were you notified (by Hendrik's comment?)

Comment: I'm still pretty certain that @genesis wasn't notified of that comment "OK, ...".

Comment: Time to catch an airplane.  I'll be back around in a few hours.  Thanks for the test @Hendrik!

Comment: @Hendrik No I was notified just about "I'm still pretty..." where you mentioned me